# Looking for the correct technique for cookie's and redirecting

Tags: javascript, cookies, redirect

So here is the situation, the website has code in the head that redirects to the mobile site. However, on the mobile site it has a link to load the actual site. I have never attempted cookies before, so would I use an onclick="dropCookie()" on the link going to the actual site then have the redirect script not redirect if that cookie is found? Any examples of how this works would be amazing! Thank you.

Comment: Are the desktop and mobile sites served by the same URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better method to redirect mobile browsers is to check the User agent (UA) string. See [this page](http://user-agent-string.info/list-of-ua#Mobile%20Browser) for a list of mobile UA strings.

If you're using PHP, use this variable to get the UA string: `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.

Comment: Yea, we decided not to use JavaScript and let the client do it. They have access to all the back-end and server side code since it's a better method.